# Delete Duplicate records using ROWNUM OR ROW_NUMBER IN Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I Have Oracle 11g. I have 4 records  and i want to delete duplicate records using ROWNUM or ROW_NUMBER.
Table is as below.

| id | name | dept | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | nikhil | prod | 12000 |
| 100 | nikhil | prod | 12000 |
| 200 | john | HR | 10000 |
| 200 | john | HR | 10000 |

And I want output like this

| id | name | dept | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | nikhil | prod | 12000 |
| 200 | john | HR | 10000 |

Comment: just use `CREATE TABLE t2 AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM t` :)

Comment: Why would you use `row_number()` instead of `select distinct`?

Answer (score 2):

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table salarytable (id int,  name varchar(50), dept varchar(50), salary  int);

 insert into salarytable values(100 ,'nikhil','prod', 12000 );
 insert into salarytable values(100, 'nikhil', 'prod', 12000); 
 insert into salarytable values(200, 'john', 'HR', 10000); 
 insert into salarytable values(200, 'john', 'HR', 10000);
```

Delete Query:

```
 DELETE FROM salarytable
 WHERE rowid not in
 (SELECT MIN(rowid)
 FROM salarytable
 GROUP BY id ,name ,dept ,salary);
```

Select Query:

```
 select * from salarytable;
```

Output:

| ID | NAME | DEPT | SALARY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | nikhil | prod | 12000 |
| 200 | john | HR | 10000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d4c181032931b5895d00a691d1a115ac)*

Delete duplicate with row_number()

Delete query with row_number():

```
 delete from salarytable
 where  rowid in
 ( select rwid
   from ( select rowid rwid
          ,      row_number() over ( partition by id order by id) rn
          from   salarytable
        )
   where  rn>1
 )
```

Select Query:

```
 select * from salarytable;
```

Output:

| ID | NAME | DEPT | SALARY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | nikhil | prod | 12000 |
| 200 | john | HR | 10000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a2e61dd0bc3b68faebaaa4614ffa16e3)*

Comment: I want using rownum

Comment: ok. let me try again. Which version of oracle you are using?

Comment: I have revised my answer with row_number()

Comment: This only considers that 2 rows are duplicates if they have the same `id` value whereas they may have the same `id` and different `name`, `dept` or `salary` and then may not be duplicates. It may be a more complete check for duplicates to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id, name, dept, salary ORDER BY ROWNUM )`.