# How to dedupe records based on start and end dates in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, plsql, duplicates

I'm trying to consolidate a table so that each record represents a time period for a given ID-Case key and each time period doesn't overlap with other records with the same keys. For example, I have this table:

[image]

I want the result table to look like this:

[image]

**NOTICE on line 7 & 8, the dates are back to back. This should be considered a continuous record.**

I've been experimenting with the LEAD and LAG OVER PARTITION functions but can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete Duplicate records using ROWNUM OR ROW\_NUMBER IN Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67239279/delete-duplicate-records-using-rownum-or-row-number-in-oracle)

Comment: No. These aren't exact records that need to be deduped so the basic answer to the attached question doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MERGE` statement and `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to find the overlaps:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name t
USING (
  SELECT rowid AS rid,
         rn,
         MAX(enddate) OVER (PARTITION BY id, code, mn) AS enddate
  FROM   table_name
  MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    PARTITION BY id, code
    ORDER BY startdate, enddate
    MEASURES
      COUNT(*) AS rn,
      MATCH_NUMBER() AS mn
    ALL ROWS PER MATCH
    PATTERN ( overlap* last_row )
    DEFINE overlap AS NEXT(startdate) <= MAX(enddate) + 1
  )
) m
ON (t.ROWID = m.rid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET   enddate = m.enddate
  DELETE WHERE rn > 1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, code, startdate, enddate) AS
  SELECT 1, 'X', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-01-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'X', DATE '2023-02-01', DATE '2023-02-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'X', DATE '2023-02-10', DATE '2023-02-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Y', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-01-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Y', DATE '2023-02-01', DATE '2023-02-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Y', DATE '2023-03-01', DATE '2023-03-31' FROM DUAL;
```

After the `MERGE` the table contains:

| ID | CODE | STARTDATE | ENDDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-30 00:00:00 |
| 1 | X | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2023-02-28 00:00:00 |
| 1 | Y | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-03-31 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8wH0Q7fs)