# Merge Date Range - SQL

Tags: sql

Can you please let me know the SQL to merge date ranges when any start date is following between start date and end date?

***Sample Data***

[image]

As per sample data,

- All data are sorted in ASC order by start Date.
- Logic:

  - Record Number 1 is not falling between any date range on table, so it can not merge with any other records.
  - Record Number 2 is falling between record number 3, so it can merge. After merge, start date will be 01/02/18 and end date will be 30/04/20.
- Like wise, from Record number 2 to Record number 6 can be merge and output will be 01/02/18 and 06/10/22

***Desired Output***

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76283955/1509264

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: 31/12/99 - which year is that 99?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MERGE` and `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name t
USING (
  SELECT rowid AS rid,
         rn,
         MAX(enddate) OVER (PARTITION BY id, mn) AS enddate
  FROM   table_name
  MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    PARTITION BY id
    ORDER BY startdate, enddate
    MEASURES
      COUNT(*) AS rn,
      MATCH_NUMBER() AS mn
    ALL ROWS PER MATCH
    PATTERN ( overlap* last_row )
    DEFINE overlap AS NEXT(startdate) <= MAX(enddate) + 1
  )
) m
ON (t.ROWID = m.rid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET   enddate = m.enddate
  DELETE WHERE rn > 1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, startdate, enddate) AS
  SELECT 1, DATE '2015-12-18', DATE '2016-05-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2018-02-01', DATE '2019-04-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2018-05-11', DATE '2020-04-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2019-01-21', DATE '2022-10-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2019-04-01', DATE '2021-06-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2021-08-05', DATE '2022-10-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2023-02-10', DATE '2099-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-01-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2023-02-01', DATE '2023-02-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2023-03-01', DATE '2023-03-31' FROM DUAL;
```

Then after the `MERGE` the table contains:

| ID | STARTDATE | ENDDATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-12-18 00:00:00 | 2016-05-09 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | 2022-10-06 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2023-02-10 00:00:00 | 2099-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-03-31 00:00:00 |

---

You can do it without `MERGE` and `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` by using analytic functions to `UPDATE` the table and then a second `DELETE` statement to remove the excess rows:

```sql
UPDATE table_name t
SET enddate = (
  SELECT enddate
  FROM   (
    SELECT CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY id, grp
                  ORDER     BY startdate, enddate
                )
           WHEN 1
           THEN MAX(enddate) OVER (PARTITION BY id, grp)
           END AS enddate
    FROM   (
      SELECT id,
             startdate,
             enddate,
             SUM(
               CASE
               WHEN startdate <= prev_enddate
               THEN 0
               ELSE 1
               END
             ) OVER (
               PARTITION BY id
               ORDER     BY startdate, enddate
             ) AS grp
      FROM   (
        SELECT t.*,
               MAX(enddate) OVER (
                 PARTITION BY id
                 ORDER     BY startdate, enddate
                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
               ) AS prev_enddate
        FROM   table_name t
      )
    )
  ) m
  WHERE t.ROWID = m.ROWID
);
```

then:

```sql
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE enddate IS NULL;
```

Which results in the same table contents.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/s_IyDnFo)

Comment: Thank you @MT0. Is there any other way we can write it into simple SQL without using merge or match recognize because I have to integrate this SQL in Spark/HIve (BigData).

Comment: @JigarGorakhiya Updated with `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements that give the same output.